# Mono(epi)morphisms as im(sub)mersions in the category of manifolds

Tags: category-theory, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, monomorphisms, diffeomorphism

In the definition of the category of smooth manifolds it's usual to take the morphisms to be simply smooth functions, and this results in having monomorfisms and epimorphisms to be injective and surjective smooth maps.

What would the morphisms need to be, with smooth manifolds as objects, to make the monos and epis to be immersions and submersions and keep diffeomorphisms as the isomorphisms? Is there a way to do this? Would that make the subobjects to be submanifolds?

Comment: It's not true that epimorphisms are surjective smooth maps--rather, they're smooth maps with dense image.

Comment: Is it because it's usual to define manifolds as Hausdorff spaces? If don't make this requirement than are the epi's just surjective?

Comment: Ah, if you don't require your manifolds to be Hausdorff then the epis are indeed the surjections.

Comment: This is exactly the question that I was thinking last two days. If you don't mind, I will post this on MO and link this.